# When does Registry.CreateSubKey return null?

Tags: c#, registry

From what I understand in the documentation, it returns null if it fails, but it seems to me there is an exception ready for every fail scenario.

In what standard scenario will this function actually return a null value?

Comment: Weird indeed. If you are really curious, download Reflector, find this method and see if/when it returns null. Might be because the underlying system call fails....

Comment: Good idea..
It's quite complicated to follow the method, but it finishes with the following two lines:

            BCLDebug.Assert(false, "Unexpected code path in RegistryKey::CreateSubKey"); 
            return null;

so I guess no "normal" call should result with a null. The resharper just doesn't see it, and warns about null return value. I'll safely ignoreit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code through Reflector, you will see that if the return from the native method `Win32Native.RegCreateKeyEx()` returns anything other than an error code of 0 or if the result of the operation is `null`, it will then return `null` back to you.

A possible failure here is if the incorrect permissions are used, causing an access denied error code to be returned.

The code behind this method is as follows:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public unsafe RegistryKey CreateSubKey(string subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity)
{
    ValidateKeyName(subkey);
    ValidateKeyMode(permissionCheck);
    this.EnsureWriteable();
    subkey = FixupName(subkey);
    if (!this.remoteKey)
    {
        RegistryKey key = this.InternalOpenSubKey(subkey, permissionCheck != RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
        if (key != null)
        {
            this.CheckSubKeyWritePermission(subkey);
            this.CheckSubTreePermission(subkey, permissionCheck);
            key.checkMode = permissionCheck;
            return key;
        }
    }
    this.CheckSubKeyCreatePermission(subkey);
    Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure = null;
    if (registrySecurity != null)
    {
        structure = new Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        structure.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
        byte[] securityDescriptorBinaryForm = registrySecurity.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm();
        byte* pDest = stackalloc byte[1 * securityDescriptorBinaryForm.Length];
        Buffer.memcpy(securityDescriptorBinaryForm, 0, pDest, 0, securityDescriptorBinaryForm.Length);
        structure.pSecurityDescriptor = pDest;
    }
    int lpdwDisposition = 0;
    SafeRegistryHandle hkResult = null;
    int errorCode = Win32Native.RegCreateKeyEx(this.hkey, subkey, 0, null, 0, GetRegistryKeyAccess(permissionCheck != RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree), structure, out hkResult, out lpdwDisposition);
    if ((errorCode == 0) && !hkResult.IsInvalid)
    {
        RegistryKey key2 = new RegistryKey(hkResult, permissionCheck != RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, false, this.remoteKey, false);
        this.CheckSubTreePermission(subkey, permissionCheck);
        key2.checkMode = permissionCheck;
        if (subkey.Length == 0)
        {
            key2.keyName = this.keyName;
            return key2;
        }
        key2.keyName = this.keyName + @"\" + subkey;
        return key2;
    }
    if (errorCode != 0)
    {
        this.Win32Error(errorCode, this.keyName + @"\" + subkey);
    }
    return null;
}
```